# CloudQueueMessage has no byte[] ctor, any explanation?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-queues

I needed to compress my string input because of the 64k message size limit.

In the documentation it says there is a public **constructor which accepts a byte[]**:

```
public CloudQueueMessage (byte[] content);
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueuemessage.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet

**Apparently this is not true for the latest SDK and the .NET builds**
*C:\Users\xyz.nuget\packages\windowsazure.storage\8.5.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll*

It is part of the .NET45 build, not any .NET Standard builds. Neither 1.0 nor 1.3 and there is no build for 2.0.

Bummer. Sure enough there still is the internal "Rawbytes[]" property.
Does anyone have any idea why it is the way it is?

Answer (score 3):

While looking at the decompiled code I found the solution.

**Update/Solution**: I just realized there is an extra public static method for what I was looking for:

```
CloudQueueMessage.CreateCloudQueueMessageFromByteArray(yourByteArray);
```

Which in turn is only a shortcut for

```
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(null);
message.SetMessageContent(yourByteArray);
```

**So to cut a long story short.**
Also with .NET Standard it is possible to create messages from byte[].
It's only the public ctor which is (somehow) missing.